# Parenthesis backslash preventing regex pattern matching

Tags: java, regex

**The input**

```
Reflux Symptom Association Probability (Impedance)
Symptom     Acid    Nonacid All Reflux

Belch       66% 0%  0%
Heartburn       98% 60% 29%
Stomach pain        96% 0%  75%
```

**The pattern match**

```
Pattern.compile("Reflux Symptom Association Probability \\(Impedance\\).*?[^\n]",Pattern.DOTALL);
```

**The output**

```
Reflux Symptom Association Probability (Impedance)
```

**The desired output**

```
Reflux Symptom Association Probability (Impedance)
    Symptom     Acid    Nonacid All Reflux

    Belch       66% 0%  0%
    Heartburn       98% 60% 29%
    Stomach pain        96% 0%  75%
```

How come I don't seem to be able to extract the whole thing.

**Note 1:** This is part of a larger document so needs to match pattern rather than `.*`

**Note 2:** When I single backslash the parentheses in a regex tester like [here](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output)
I do seem to be able to get the whole match.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `.*?[^\n]` means: the shortest possible sequence of any characters, followed by something that is not a newline. In your case, you probably have a `\r` before your newline, so that shortest sequence has zero characters. It is unclear from your question how you would want to recognize the boundaries of your section in the bigger document - you haven't made an attempt to do that in your regex.

Comment: Also, you haven't posted an [mcve] that generates any output.